# How to find which posts have the highest comments and which posts have the fewest comments?

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to postgreSQl and SQL and databases, I hope you guys can help me with this, i want to know which posts have the most amount of comments and which have the least amount of comments and the users need to be specified too.

```
CREATE SCHEMA perf_demo;
SET search_path TO perf_demo;

-- Tables
CREATE TABLE users(
  id     SERIAL       -- PRIMARY KEY
, email  VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE posts(
  id       SERIAL        -- PRIMARY KEY
, user_id  INTEGER       NOT NULL  -- REFERENCES users(id)
, title    VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE comments(
  id       SERIAL        -- PRIMARY KEY
, user_id  INTEGER       NOT NULL  -- REFERENCES users(id)
, post_id  INTEGER       NOT NULL  -- REFERENCES posts(id)
, body     VARCHAR(500)  NOT NULL
);

-- Generate approx. N users
-- Note: NULL values might lead to lesser rows than N value.
INSERT INTO users(email)
WITH query AS (
    SELECT 'user_' || seq || '@' 
        || ( CASE (random() * 5)::INT
                WHEN 0 THEN 'my'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'your'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'his'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'her'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'our'
             END ) 
        || '.mail' AS email
    FROM generate_series(1, 5) seq              -- Important: Replace N with a useful value
)
SELECT email 
FROM query 
WHERE email IS NOT NULL;

-- Generate N posts
INSERT INTO posts(user_id, title)
WITH expanded AS (
    SELECT random(), seq, u.id AS user_id
    FROM generate_series(1, 8) seq, users u     -- Important: Replace N with a useful value
), 
shuffled AS (
    SELECT e.*
    FROM expanded e
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ei.seq, min(ei.random) FROM expanded ei GROUP BY ei.seq
    ) em ON (e.seq = em.seq AND e.random = em.min)
    ORDER BY e.seq
)
-- Top 20 programming languages: https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/
SELECT s.user_id,
    'Let''s talk about (' || s.seq || ') '
    || ( CASE (random() * 19 + 1)::INT
            WHEN 1 THEN 'C'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Python'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Java'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'C++'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'C#'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Visual Basic'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'JavaScript'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'Assembly language'
            WHEN 9 THEN 'PHP'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'SQL'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'Ruby'
            WHEN 12 THEN 'Classic Visual Basic'
            WHEN 13 THEN 'R'
            WHEN 14 THEN 'Groovy'
            WHEN 15 THEN 'MATLAB'
            WHEN 16 THEN 'Go'
            WHEN 17 THEN 'Delphi/Object Pascal'
            WHEN 18 THEN 'Swift'
            WHEN 19 THEN 'Perl'
            WHEN 20 THEN 'Fortran'
        END ) AS title
FROM shuffled s;

-- Generate N comments
-- Note: The cross-join is a performance killer. 
--       Try the SELECT without INSERT with small N values to get an estimation of the execution time.
--       With these values you can extrapolate the execution time for a bigger N value.
INSERT INTO comments(user_id, post_id, body)
WITH expanded AS (
    SELECT random(), seq, u.id AS user_id, p.id AS post_id
    FROM generate_series(1, 10) seq, users u, posts p   -- Important: Replace N with a useful value
), 
shuffled AS (
    SELECT e.*
    FROM expanded e
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT ei.seq, min(ei.random) FROM expanded ei GROUP BY ei.seq ) em ON (e.seq = em.seq AND e.random = em.min)
    ORDER BY e.seq
)
SELECT s.user_id, s.post_id, 'Here some comment: ' || md5(random()::text) AS body
FROM shuffled s;
```

Could someone show me how this could be done please, I am new to SQL/postgres any help would be much appreciated. an Example would be very helpful too.

Comment: What do you mean by `the users need to be specified too` ? Do you need min/max number of comments per user per post ? Or only min/max per user ?  It would be useful if you can specify how the output should look like

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I need to only know which post had the least comments and which post had the highest comments  and this needs to be done in Common table expressions which I am not familiar with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good effort in pasting the whole dataset creation procedure, is what it needs to be included in order to make the example reproducible.

Let's start first with, how to `join` several tables: you have your `posts` table which contains the `user_id` and we can use it to join with `users` with the following.

```
SELECT email, 
    users.id user_id, 
    posts.id post_id, 
    title
from posts join users 
    on posts.user_id=users.id;
```

This will list the posts together with the authors. Check the joining condition (after the `ON`) stating the fields we're using. The result should be similar to the below

```
      email       | user_id | post_id |                 title                  
------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------
 user_1@her.mail  |       1 |       5 | Let's talk about (5) Visual Basic
 user_1@her.mail  |       1 |       2 | Let's talk about (2) Assembly language
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       8 | Let's talk about (8) R
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       7 | Let's talk about (7) Perl
 user_4@her.mail  |       4 |       6 | Let's talk about (6) Visual Basic
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       4 | Let's talk about (4) R
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       3 | Let's talk about (3) C
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       1 | Let's talk about (1) Ruby
(8 rows)
```

Now it's time to join this result, with the `comments` table. Since a `post` can have comments or not and you want to show all posts even if you don't have any comments you should use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (more info about join types [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-joins/)

So let's rewrite the above to include `comments`

```
SELECT email, 
    users.id user_id, 
    posts.id post_id, 
    title,
    comments.body
from posts 
join users 
    on posts.user_id=users.id
left outer join comments
    on posts.id = comments.post_id
    ;
```

Check out the join between `posts` and `comments` based on `post_id`.

The result of the query is the list of posts, related author and comments, similar to the below

```
      email       | user_id | post_id |                 title                  |                        body                         
------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 user_1@her.mail  |       1 |       5 | Let's talk about (5) Visual Basic      | 
 user_1@her.mail  |       1 |       2 | Let's talk about (2) Assembly language | 
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       8 | Let's talk about (8) R                 | Here some comment: 200bb07acfbac893aed60e018b47b92b
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       8 | Let's talk about (8) R                 | Here some comment: 66159adaed11404b1c88ca23b6a689ef
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       8 | Let's talk about (8) R                 | Here some comment: e5cc1f7c10bb6103053bf281d3cadb60
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       8 | Let's talk about (8) R                 | Here some comment: 5ae8674c2ef819af0b1a93398efd9418
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       7 | Let's talk about (7) Perl              | Here some comment: 5b818da691c1570dcf732ed8f6b718b3
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       7 | Let's talk about (7) Perl              | Here some comment: 88a990e9495841f8ed628cdce576a766
 user_4@her.mail  |       4 |       6 | Let's talk about (6) Visual Basic      | 
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       4 | Let's talk about (4) R                 | Here some comment: ed19bb476eb220d6618e224a0ac2910d
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       3 | Let's talk about (3) C                 | Here some comment: 23cd43836a44aeba47ad212985f210a7
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       1 | Let's talk about (1) Ruby              | Here some comment: b83999120bd2bb09d71aa0c6c83a05dd
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       1 | Let's talk about (1) Ruby              | Here some comment: b4895f4e0aa0e0106b5d3834af80275e
(13 rows)
```

Now you can start aggregating and counting comments for a certain post. You can use PG's [aggregation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), we'll use the `COUNT` here.

```
SELECT email, 
    users.id user_id, 
    posts.id post_id, 
    title,
    count(comments.id) nr_comments
from posts 
join users 
    on posts.user_id=users.id
left outer join comments
    on posts.id = comments.post_id
group by email, 
    users.id, 
    posts.id, 
    title
    ;
```

Check out that we're counting the `comments.id` field but we could also perform a `count(*)` which just counts the rows. Also check that we are grouping our results by `email`, `users.id`, `post.id` and `title`, the columns we are showing alongside the count.

The result should be similar to

```
      email       | user_id | post_id |                 title                  | nr_comments 
------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------------
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       7 | Let's talk about (7) Perl              |           2
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       3 | Let's talk about (3) C                 |           1
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       1 | Let's talk about (1) Ruby              |           2
 user_3@her.mail  |       3 |       8 | Let's talk about (8) R                 |           4
 user_1@her.mail  |       1 |       5 | Let's talk about (5) Visual Basic      |           0
 user_5@your.mail |       5 |       4 | Let's talk about (4) R                 |           1
 user_4@her.mail  |       4 |       6 | Let's talk about (6) Visual Basic      |           0
 user_1@her.mail  |       1 |       2 | Let's talk about (2) Assembly language |           0
(8 rows)
```

This should be the result you're looking for. Just bear in mind, that you're showing the user from `users` who wrote the post, not the one who commented. To view who commented you'll need to change the joining conditions.

Comment: Hello @Ftisiot How do I do this in Common table expressions? and choose the posts with the least number of comments and the highest number of comments i am a bit confused

Comment: Check out how you can use [RANK](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/) to order the resultset above by the `nr_comments` field.